# R error is.tsibble()` was deprecated in tsibble 0.8.4 and is now defunct

Tags: r

Im am trying to split my Time series data with ts_split function and I am getting this error (is.tsibble()` was deprecated in tsibble 0.8.4 and is now defunct) can someone help?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Where does `ts_split` come from?

Comment: ts_split comes from the package TSstudio and is a function to split your time series in training and testing periods.

Comment: It looks like the `TSstudio` used a function call from one if its dependencies (the `tsibble` pacakge) that is no longer available. You can [file an issue](https://github.com/RamiKrispin/TSstudio/issues) with the package developer so they fix it. They should be using `is_tsibble` rather than `is.tsibble`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!